# Object value undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, scope, express

I'm having trouble defining values in a way that I can call them later on.

If i define Search first, then Search.commands[3] is undefined.
If i define commandList first then commandList.commands[0] is undefined.

Is there a better way to define these objects such that the order doesn't matter?

```
var Search = {
    'str': 'search',
    'param': 'search',
    'action': '',
    'commands': [
        Category,
        Location,
        Sort,
        commandList
    ]
}

var commandList = {
'commands': [
    Search,
    Category,
    Stop
]
}
```

Comment: From the looks of it, `commandList[0]` will be undefined regardless of ordering.

Comment: Sorry I mean commandList.commands[0]. Fixing now.

Comment: order will matter. Just like you can not walk through a door before opening it. If you are not sure of the order, you need to code some logic into the page and loading the values when all the data is ready and already loaded.

Comment: @epascarello is there away to make sure the objects are initialized before any functions are called?

Comment: Also, you should edit your post and get that last bracket in the code box.

Comment: Libraries like require.js and such.

Comment: you need to add quotes around values.

Comment: @chovy Those values are objects not strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var Search = {
    'str': 'search',
    'param': 'search',
    'action': ''
};
var commandList = {
    'commands': [
        Search,
        Category,
        Stop
    ]
};
Search.commands = [
    Category,
    Location,
    Sort,
    commandList
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
var Search = {
    'str': 'search',
    'param': 'search',
    'action': ''
};

var commandList = {
};



Search.commands = [
        Category,
        Location,
        Sort,
        commandList
    ];

commandList.commands = [
    Search,
    Category,
    Stop
];
```